# What does symbols in google maps (when looking for some location in uk) mean?

Tags: uk, public-transport

I was looking for route from LHR to Oxford in google maps.

There are some symbols which I do not understand, for example there is a symbol that has two arrows in opposite direction as in the following attached picture.

[image]

What does those symbols mean?

Comment: If all you are seeking is transport from LHR to Oxford then use the coach: Oxford Bus Company, The Airline. It's much the simplest journey.

Comment: @erstwhileeditor I did not understand "the coach: Oxford Bus Company, The Airline".. what does it mean :)

Comment: If I use https://www.traveline.info/ and just specify Heathrow Airport and Oxford, Oxfordshire (it has a little map icon next to it -- not a bus stop, not a train station) then I saw direct coach connections so I forced it to only use coaches and then I get this: [![schedule from the site: ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXKJc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXKJc.png) So much better than the two connection options from Google Maps!

Comment: https://airline.oxfordbus.co.uk/ gives all the info. (I think by putting Oxford Rail Station you have confused Google).

Comment: The bus service confusingly named "The Airline" is pretty fast and frequent for Heathrow-Oxford. I've taken it a few times. I didn't much like the seats, but it wins on convenience and simplicity. It's even a few pounds cheaper than the cheapest train tickets (which require at least two changes and can be up to an hour slower).

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You want to travel from Heathrow to Oxford. The Oxford Bus Company runs a coach service called "The Airline". You should use that: it's quicker, more convenient and cheaper than the train. (I live in Oxford, fly from Heathrow a few times a year.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NationalRail.svg) represents [National Rail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Rail), an association representing rail service in the UK. It's based on the logo of the former [British Rail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail). The symbol is displayed in Google Maps, on maps, signs, and other transit to indicate train service (GWR, CrossCountry, and Heathrow Express are the names of different train operating companies in the UK)

The other symbols in your image:

- U3, OXF, 1, RA1: bus service
- Piccadilly: London Underground (tube) service

Clicking on a route in Google Maps will provide more details about the services it contains.

Comment: If you're curious, it stylistically represents a railway - the two horizontal lines being two tracks for trains travelling in opposite directions, and the zigzag actually being two arrows pointing in the direction of travel (since trains generally drive on the left in this country).